# How to redirect to 0.0.0.0 of web-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, io-redirection

I'm running a rails application which redirects the incoming requests to 0.0.0.0:3000

On my local machine it works since I'm running my mongrel server on 0.0.0.0:3000 but when I make an HTTP request to my remote server it redicts me to my workstation's 0.0.0.0:3000 but I want it to redict the request to its own 0.0.0.0:3000

I'm using mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 as webserver on ubuntu 10.04

Comment: how are you doing this redirect? if you issue a redirect to "0.0.0.0", your browser will always attempt to reach your own machine. I suggest you just want to redirect to "/"

Comment: I'm using 'redirect_to' for redirection. Are there any alternative methods for redirection?

Comment: redirect_to what? `redirect_to "0.0.0.0:3000"` is very specific. I suggest you should always redirect to a relative path, eg. `redirect_to "/"`. Unless you are trying to specify a canonical host name.

Comment: `redirect_to domain_url(:custom => _current_group.domain)` which will redirect user to sub-domain assigned to his group. If i wouldn't have used sub-domains here, I would have used relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address 0.0.0.0 will always map to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), but it differs from localhost in that, when it is bound to, it is listening on all interfaces, and thus the web server can be accessed from any machine by using its hostname/IP address. If the web server listens on localhost it can only be accessed from the same machine.

Redirecting to 0.0.0.0 in your application, thus, *doesn't really make any sense*, because you're redirecting in the context of the client, not the server.

(To find a solution that does what you expect, you'd need to tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish by doing this)

Comment: In development environment, application was hosted on 0.0.0.0 but in production environment I should bind mogrel to my IP so it will redirect users to my IP instead of 0.0.0.0. I was starting my my mongrel with IP 0.0.0.0 and that was the problem. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

As I know 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable ip that a host claims as its own when it has not yet been assigned an address. Webserver has nothing to do with this address.

Comment: 0.0.0.0/8 has nothing to do with whether an IP address has been assigned or not. Self-assigned addresses are in the 169.254.0.0/16 block.

Comment: This doesn't seem to agree with the description in [RFC 5735](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735). Besides, 0.0.0.0 isn't "assigned" when there is no IP address, it just always is. If it was only used when the host didn't have an IP, then accessing it wouldn't work when you're actually connected to a network.